# Does anyone know how to access CoreData from a WebView within an Adobe DPS app?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiwebview, adobe, local-storage

When IOS5 came out, Apple made localStorage not persistent (http://www.sencha.com/blog/html5-scorecard-the-new-ipad-and-ios-5-1). While a PhoneGap application can work around this using a plug-in, we're trying to do this from within an Adobe DPS app where there is no direct access to the IOS native API nor is there a plug-in model.

We've thought of the semi-ugly workaround of using a cookie for persistence of very small data, but this is not a great solution for larger blocks of content (say an XML file and images) that need to be stored offline. Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: No you can't access any native APIs from a webview in an Adobe DPS app, but you can use web storage.

As an alternative to cookies (which have a relatively low limit on data), you can use [WebSQL or localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

I've successfully used both in a DPS app :)

Anecdotally, I find localStorage much nicer to use than webSQL, but if you know SQL and need to store complex relationships it may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Without direct access to the IOS native API you will not be able to access CoreData that is for sure. I would say your only option is to use cookies as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks, Oscar. If only my data was less than 4k in size... :-(